# Postgres - create temp table with SELECT and ON COMMIT DROP

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

In postgres(9.4) I am trying to create a temporary table from select and apply "on commit drop" to same table. I am using below syntax.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t5 ON COMMIT DROP AS select * from test4
```

It gives messages

```
Query returned successfully: 5 rows affected, 62 ms execution time.
```

But when i query the same table,

```
select * from t5
```

It throws error,

```
ERROR:  relation "t5" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from t5
                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "t5" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 15
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my understanding what is the mistake i am committing here.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the temp table is being dropped as soon as the select finishes, when it also has finished just being created.  What exact behavior are you looking for here?

Comment: As Tim said: you probably have autocommit enabled and thus the `create table` statement is automatically committed and thus the temp table is dropped

Answer (score 28):

You need to be in a transaction otherwise every single query is performed in its own transaction.

```
BEGIN; -- start transaction

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t5 ON COMMIT DROP AS select * from test4;

select * from t5;

COMMIT; -- drops the temp table
```

Comment: Yes @Eleke, you are right. This works when i put in a block. Thanks